# LTSPICE - Scale dimensions

Tags: ltspice, scaling

I want to specify the scaling factors for my mosfet dimensions. How do I do it ?

I am following some beginner tutorials but they have done everything in HSPICE. I use LTSPICE. And LTSPICE doesnt seem to have a scale option.

I looked at all the options here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gnucap/gnucap-man-html/gnucap-man042.html

But there's no option to specify scale factor.

There are DEFL and DEFW options but they dont specify scale.

How do I go about it ?

Thanks

Comment: Need more context, what model are you working with?

Comment: @laptop2d. I've just begun studying. So I am using Predictive Technology Model 180nm for simple inverter.

Answer (score 1):

First you need some model files for your transistors. The model files need to be included by using the `.lib` command. Make sure that the model file takes care of calculating the dimensions required to get the parasitic capacitances.

You need to use generic transistors (`nmos4`, `pmos4`).

The scaling is simply done by specifying the w (width) and l (length) of the transistor.

See the example below.

[image]

Comment: I just copied the PTM model from here-> http://ptm.asu.edu/modelcard/180nm_bulk.txt   into a .spice file and included it in my netlist. Is it Ok ? Also by scaling I mean..like setting the default dimension..like I set Lambda=90n and then specify all dimensions like W=2 for 2 Lambda, L=4 for 4 Lambda and so on...Can it be done ?

Comment: What should lambda be? The parameter for channel length modulation?

Comment: It doesn't work like this. Model files are specific to a certain technology. Your model file is for a 180nm technology.

Comment: Oh Ok. I was following the tutorial. So there they had used .option scale=0.01u for this same thing(HSPICE though)..and then specified L=36 W=72 and so on..so I guess L means 36*0.01u ...correct ?? I was trying to replicate that in LTSPICE but it would not recognize scale option. I'm not sure now whats going on

Comment: I never use HSPICE, but I guess you are right since 0.36um would be twice the minimum channel length.

Comment: Well....did you do something like this (I mean that scaling kinda factor?) in LTSPICE ? It would be a real time saver if I could specify dimensions like this rather than doing '2*LAMBDA' or so to every dimension...

Comment: There is the `.param` command, but I doubt that this is a time saver.

Comment: I'm currently using that only..but again its a real pain